# SQL: use distinct values in one column to select all corresponding distinct values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

Suppose I have a data set such as this:

```
ColA    ColB
====    ====
Foo     Green
Foo     Purple
Bar     Magenta
Bar     Green
Foo     Purple
Bar     Purple
Bar     Purple
Foo     Green
Bar     Green
```

I would like to query this data and return the below. Essentially, take all distinct values from ColA (Foo & Bar) and return all distinct values for EACH of them from ColB:

```
ColA    ColB
====    ====
Foo     Green
Foo     Purple
Bar     Magenta
Bar     Green
Bar     Purple
```

I know I'm overthinking this...but I can't seem to hammer it out...

Comment: just use `distinct`

Answer (score 1):

Please use of of the below -

```
SELECT DISTINCT cola,colb FROM yourtableName
```

OR

```
SELECT cola,colb From yourtableName
GROUP BY cola,colb
```